# QString: Unicode encoding-decoding problem

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to make a simple conversion to Unicode string to standart string, but no success.

I have: `PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'\xc5\x9f')`

I want: `'\xc5\x9f'`  notice str type not unicode, because the library I am using is not accepting unicode.

Here is what I tried, you can see how hopeless I am :) :

```
>>> s = QtCore.QString(u'\xc5\x9f')
>>> str(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128) '
>>> s.toUtf8()
PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray('\xc3\x85\xc2\x9f')
>>> s.toUtf8().decode("utf-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QByteArray' object has no attribute 'decode'
>>> str(s.toUtf8()).decode("utf-8")
u'\xc5\x9f'
>>> str(str(s.toUtf8()).decode("utf-8"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I know there are a lot of questions related to Unicode, but I can't find this answer.

What should I do?

Edit:

I found a hacky way:

```
>>> unicoded = str(s.toUtf8()).decode("utf-8")
>>> unicoded
u'\xc5\x9f'
>>> eval(repr(unicoded)[1:])
'\xc5\x9f'
```

Do you know a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
In [23]: a
Out[23]: u'\xc5\x9f'

In [24]: a.encode('latin-1')
Out[24]: '\xc5\x9f'

In [25]: type(a.encode('latin-1'))
Out[25]: <type 'str'>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have unicode string of QString data type , and need to convert it to python string , you just :

```
unicode(YOUR_QSTRING_STRING)
```